# Read from Registry in a windows 10 minifilter driver

Tags: c, windows, registry, driver, minifilter

I'm working on a windows 10 filesystem mini filter driver and I want to read from the registry. Unfortunately, I'm new to c and driver development. My question is how do I receive the key value from the `PKEY_VALUE_FULL_INFORMATION` structure. (using the ZwOpenKey and ZwQueryValueKey routines). [In the msdn doc for this structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_key_value_full_information), I didn't understand how to use the `DataOffset` property.
Also I didn't understand why it says the `Name` is a string of unicode characters when its declared as `WCHAR Name[1];`.

Comment: Are you sure you need `KeyValueFullInformation` and not `KeyValuePartialInformation`? The second does not read key name. Do you know the type of the registry key in advance (DWORD, string etc)?

Comment: I managed to get the data this way, thanks!